# Flow Error: If that user is inactive, the interviews can't resume

Tags: process-builder

**Background**

An employee recently left the company and their Salesforce user was set to inactive, and I received this error message:

> Every waiting flow interview has an associated user — the person who
>   caused the interview to start waiting. If that user is inactive, the
>   interviews can't resume.
>
> Sean Spicer (0050O000008XXXX) is inactive, so please delete the
>   following flow interviews.

**Questions**

1. How can I make sure the scheduled actions still occur?
2. Can I re-assign ownership of the scheduled actions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't possible to change the owner/user for a "waiting" flow interview.  The best (and only, I believe) way to handle this is to re-activate and then ["freeze"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_freeze.htm&type=5)   the user.  Once all the flow interviews related to the user are complete, you can deactivate the user's account.

There is an open feature request to allow flows to function when the associated user is inactive, but it's still under the point threshold:

- [Idea: Flows created by user should not fail when user becomes inactive](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cM8AQAU)

Comment: Do they need a full user license or can they be Chatter users?

Comment: Unfortunately, a Chatter license won't get you there (yet).  Right now, downgrading from a standard or platform license to a Chatter Free license removes all past activity, including Chatter history. There is an idea under review that would allow users to be downgraded while retaining Chatter history, but no word on anything on the roadmap to allow more that that, as far as I know.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KUIzAAO

Answer (score 0):

I have applied this work around to handle this issue.
Setup a schedule flow to run each day and find records that needs an update (The same action that was waiting in Time based workflow).

Delete all existing time based workflow  for the action as no need to keep adding the time based workflows all the actions can be scheduled for the same date the TBW was suppose to trigger.

I have a similar issue where process builder set the contract to expired, one day after the contract end date. will be running a scheduled flow to check all the active contracts with contract end date passed yesterday and apply the same update action. No need to keep the user in frozen state :).